# Is there any 24/7 store in Turku?

Tags: finland

When you're a tourist in Turku sometimes you need to get things like a toothbrush in the middle of the night.

Is there any 24/7 supermarket in Turku/Åbo?

Comment: Most larger Finnish cities have some gas/petrol stations with an attached 24/7 convenience store.

Comment: Unless it is for food after a delayed arrival (and no food available on the transport) you can wait till the shops open the next day. Your teeth will not fall out if you ignore brushing them for a night.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the Sale Koulukatu supermarket, when typed into Google it shows being open 24 hours every day.

It’s location:

- Koulukatu 29, 20100 Turku, Finland

Comment: Ah, 800 meters by foot from where I stayed 

Comment: @HankyPanky no, I just didn't know it was there. There were 3 supermarkets within 100 meters but all closed before 23:00.

Comment: It's part of an ABC gas station, so look out for that. _Tervetuloa Turkuun!_